# Follow up section on a question

Tags: feature-request

I would like to see an option available to the OP where they can return to their question once their issue has been addressed/resolved/concluded to say what happened.

For "how should I..." questions, it would be so nice to read the original question, the answers and comments and then have the OP tell what hey finally did and what happened would be very useful - it would give some context to how the answers helped or hindered their particular situation

The section should NOT be about expanding the original question or asking another question/starting the discussion cycle again. It should be simply a decsription o what action they took (and why) and what it resulted in

Example question - [How should I tell a coworker that his headphones are too loud?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/how-should-i-tell-a-coworker-their-headphones-are-too-loud)

Example "follow up" - "We took the entire team to the cafe area of our building for a coffee to discuss several work matters. One item on the agenda was office environment and I was nominated to bring the matter up in a very general/non individual way. Everyone agreed without feeling singled out and since that day last week, my co-worker has noticeably lowered the volume on their headphones"

Comment: Some OPs simply come back and edit the original question to provide the follow-up you are looking for. Some don't bother.

Comment: the way you describe it, such a follow-up makes a reasonably good match for an answer (and I even recall seeing follow-ups at other sites submitted as answers). Given that [self-answering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/self-answer/info) is considered a legitimate and respectable practice across SE network, why not use it?

Comment: I've wished for this so many times.  I think if writing follow ups was formalized and promoted to some extent, people would do it.  As it stands OPs may wonder if anyone is interested anymore, but I would say it's immensely valuable not only to answerers but also future visitors.  Completing the feedback loop also validates or invalidates answers.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think that if the question is good, then these would make great blog posts to explain:

1. What advice you did/didn't take
2. What the results were
3. Whether or not you'd come back to TWP to ask in the future

Unfortunately, we aren't quite at that point yet. Generally we've been pretty lax about allowing people to have significant edits including follow-up info, but moving forward we probably want to avoid it, which is why I suggest some blog posts instead.

Answer (score 2):

In the interests of keeping the Stack Exchange engine standardized throughout the network, I'd say simply adding the follow up as an answer would be best.  After all, this seems to work really well on Stack Overflow. Many times we see askers come back and post their solution as an answer.

If their answer is the one that solved their problem, they can even mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is what I was advised to do the first time [I faced this issue](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15285/472).