# Standard way to add follow up to a question I asked

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

I recently asked a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95725/handling-unusual-email-from-possible-recruit) and received some great answers that guided me to handle the situation.

Today (some days later), after addressing the problem with the person involved, I have some new details on the source of the problem and the outcome the way it was handled. I consider those details relevant, as they reflect that the interpretation of the answerers was indeed correct, and I **intend to add those details as a follow up** to the question so it is documented and helps future users.

**Question: Is there is a standard way to do this?** Or if there is not, what would be the best thing to do? I have seen in this and other SE networks that sometimes users edit their questions and add an "Update:..." section where they explain those follow up details that they also consider useful. This I consider most appropriate.

However, searching some old posts I found a *feature request* titled [Follow up section on a question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/follow-up-section-on-a-question/2454#2454), where some users argue against that request in favor of either **write a blog post** (too complex for just wanting to add some details) or **add a question to my own answer** (my question is already answered and the details themselves are not a valid answer).

Another option could be to **add a comment** with the details, but doing that may result in not giving enough relevance to them and also end up with an unnecessary long comment (even longer than permitted). How could I approach this situation?

Comment: Yeah, I think what @MaskedMan suggested is probably your best bet.