# Situation Updates

Tags: discussion, editing, duplicates, new-users

A recent user asked a question about 1.5 months ago regarding his/her boss and how he/she should respond.

[Do I confront my boss](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99186/do-i-confront-my-boss?noredirect=1#comment302967_99186)

Although the question was initially down-voted, the user received a number of helpful suggestions on how to resolve the workplace situation.

Recently the user asked what appears to be a duplicate of the original question.

[Working with a Difficult Coworker and an Unhelpful Boss](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96385/working-with-a-difficult-coworker-and-an-unhelpful-boss?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Despite the negative response to what appears to be a duplicate question. I wonder if the workplace has a mechanism for updates. Not updates in terms of editing the question, but in terms of an appropriate format.

If a user has a development to a situation and edits the original question, most likely it won't receive attention to reflect the updated situation as most answers would be based upon past conditions. Plus people are busy, chances are they won't revise all of their past answers to reflect the most up to date situation.

Likewise if the same situation + development is asked as a standalone question, it runs the risk of a duplicate flag.

With this said, what would be the most ideal solution?

Edit the original and ask for revised and new answers or create a new question with the development and acknowledge its history and allow for more discussion?

Comment: Are you asking about this specific case or about a general situation? Without looking at either question the general guideline would presumably be that OPs should refer to the previous question for additional background if they're asking a *new* question but that an identical question with the only difference being "this has been going on for X months longer" is a simple repost which should be removed.

Comment: General situation, but the answer(s) thus far hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With this said, what would be the most ideal solution? Edit the original and ask for revised and new answers or create a new question with the development and acknowledge its history and allow for more discussion?

I would say it depends on the new version of the question, and if it is *really* similar to the last one or not.

If it *is* really similar or exactly the same, I would suggest to **edit the question** to reflect those minor differences and then **offer a bounty** on that question, to attract more users and get better answers. That in fact is the built-in mecanism in SE when you are not satisfied with the answers received (or they don't completely solve the problem).

Now, if the question *is not* that similar, and has certain details that deviate or differentiate from the first question, I would recommend to **ask a new question**, possibly **linking to the first question** and explaining why and how this one is different and, if it applies, why the other answers did not work so good (so it does not get closed as dupe of the first one or people copy answers given on the first one).

In the case where users are not able to offer bounties ther are fewer options, as they are limited to asking a new question, or editing their posts and hoping people will take the time to rethink and re-read their previous answers.

That being said, it is important to notice that *engaging and commenting questions when you ask them* is really important, so answerers can fine-tune their posts to better fit your needs and you have greater chances of getting the answer you need in the first question (skipping this whole bounty or new question situation).

Comment: New users often don't have the means to offer a bounty. But it would appear that the lines are greyed when one decides between one or the other.

Comment: Yes, as a new user it is often not as easy to navigate through *any* SE site like you would when you have higher reputation. That is why the importance of engaging and doing follow up to your question, instead of just "posting and logging off".

Comment: FWIW, I asked a question here on meta some months ago about [Standard way to add follow-up to a question I asked](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/standard-way-to-add-follow-up-to-a-question-i-asked), which was a dupe of other questions related to this that you are saying, you may find it helpful to read my question and the dupes it points to.

Comment: Noted and read. It does help. Thanks.